# How to set multiple value in a form ? Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First time to post smth on stackoverflow, so hopping to be clear enough :).

I have built an app where you need to sign up with your professionnel address email and thanks to your email domain name you are being redirected on the group of your company. Ex: if my email is example@companyone.com, i will be redirected on the group called companyone. 
Now, i want to allow someone with a different domain name email address to access the same group, by adding a second value in my admin console  in the email_domain_name input. I can't figure it out...

Here is my code:

admin group model:

```
f.inputs "Details" do
  f.input :name
  f.input :description
  f.input :email_domain_name
  f.input :slug
  f.input :picture, as: :file
end
```

Registration controller:

```
def check_group_domain_name
unless Group.find_by(email_domain_name: Mail::Address.new(params[:user][:email]).domain)
  flash[:notice] = t('users.sign_in.invalid')
end
end
```

Model User:

```
def assign_to_group
 self.group = Group.find_by(email_domain_name: Mail::Address.new(self.email).domain)
end
```

Email_validator:

```
  class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    domain_names = Group.all.pluck(:email_domain_name)
    begin
      m = Mail::Address.new(value)
      r = m.domain!=nil && m.domain.match(Regexp.union(domain_names)) && m.address == value
    rescue Exception => e
      r = false
    end
    record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is invalid") unless 
r
  end
  end
```

Comment: Do you want `email_domain_name` to be able to store multiple email addresses?

Comment: Yep exactly. I need demail_domain_name to store multiple value which are domain name such as: apple.com, algolia.com . For now, i can only store one.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an alt_email_domain_name field, and look up the group by that if the first fails. Does the user need to have a valid email for that alternate domain? Little confused as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Alternatively, you could allow for comma separated email domains in the field, split them, and check for both domain groups.

Comment: Sorry, i know that is not really clear. I don't need the user to have a valid email but i need 2 users with 2 different emails to redirect on the same group (if i have it specified beforehand in the admin console). For ex, i have currently for one group, email_domain_name: "edhec.com". I would like to store more than just this one, and have for example email_domain_name: "edhec.com, hec.com" to redirect on this group all people signing up with hec.com & edhec.com email address.  It is clearer ... ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can store comma seperated domain_names and while querying you do `ilike` search.
If you expect the list to be huge than you need to define it as `text` instead of `string`.

You can list them down too like,

```
Group.first.email_domain_name.split(',')
```

Another recommended solution if you are using postges as db is to use [Array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html) datatype